RTL Layout Issues in React Native App After EAS Build
I've built a React Native app using Expo, aiming for a fully RTL (Right-to-Left) interface. During development on my Android device, everything renders as expected. However, after building the app and extracting the APKs, the RTL layout seems to be off.
Development Environment:
Framework: React Native with Expo
Development Device: Android
RTL Implementation: Using flexDirection: "row-reverse" and textAlign: "right"
In the development environment, the UI elements are placed correctly. For example, a name like "امیر" is positioned in the top right corner as intended.
Build Process:

I use eas build -p android to build the app.

After downloading the
.aab file, I run:
java -jar bundletool-all-1.17.2.jar build-apks --bundle=application-4786.aab --output=myapp.apks --mode=universal --ks=my-release-key.jks --ks-key-alias=my-key-alias --ks-pass=pass:PASSSSSSS

Then, I extract the APKs:
unzip myapp.apks -d myapp


Issue:
After building and deploying the app, the layout issues arise:
The UI elements that should be in the top right corner are instead positioned in the top left corner.
Questions:

Could the issue be related to the flexDirection: "row-reverse"
usage? Should I be using "row" instead, considering a different
build behavior?
What steps can I take to ensure consistent RTL behavior across
development and production builds?

Thanks in advance!
